# Pandas Dataframe: Replace substring in col1 identified by string in col2, with string from col3

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame where my problem can be simplified to the below example. I'd like to replace part of a string in one column that's identified by a string in a second column, with a string specified in a 3rd column.

Example data frame:

```
main_string          | target | replacement
Hello My Name is XXX | XXX    | John
Hello My name is YYY | YYY    | Mary
Hello my Name is Rob | Nan    | None
Hello My name is ZZZ | ZZZ    | Kate
```

And my target output is, in a new dataframe column:

```
Hello My Name is John
Hello My name is Mary
Hello my Name is Rob 
Hello My name is Kate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom lambda function with `if-else` for test missing values `NaN` or `None` like `Nonetype`:

```
f = lambda x: x['main_string'].replace(x['target'], x['replacement']) 
              if pd.notna(x['target']) 
              else x['main_string']
df['out'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
print (df)
            main_string target replacement                    out
0  Hello My Name is XXX    XXX        John  Hello My Name is John
1  Hello My name is YYY    YYY        Mary  Hello My name is Mary
2  Hello my Name is Rob    Nan        None   Hello my Name is Rob
3  Hello My name is ZZZ    ZZZ        Kate  Hello My name is Kate
```

Alternative solution with list comprehension:

```
df['out'] = [a.replace(b, c) if pd.notna(b) else a 
             for a,b,c in df[['main_string','target','replacement']].to_numpy()]
```

Answer (score 0):

One can use Pandas' replace() function with a dictionary like this example
https://cmdlinetips.com/2021/04/pandas-replace-to-one-or-more-column-values-python/

Comment: Thanks. I had thought of this way but unfortunately on the real data it wouldn't be very efficient compared to the above because each row would be checked against every dictionary item (which would have been superfluous with the data already in the correct row)